# Multiple pouchdbs vs single pouchdb

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb, couchdb-2.0

I created couchdb with multiple dbs for use in my ionic 3 app. Also upon integrating it with pouchdb for client side syncing i created seperate pouchdbs for each one of the dbs. Total 5 pouchdbs. My question

1. whether it is good idea storing multiple pouchdbs on client side owing to the no. of http connections that would be created by syncing the pouchdbs. Or shall I put all Couchdb databases into one database and use type fields to separate the docs. Then only one pouchdb need to be created and synced on client.
2. Also using pouchdb-authenticaion plugin, authentication data is valid for only the database on which signup/login methods were called. Accessing other databases returns unauthenticated.

Answer (score 0):

I would say, if your pouchdbs are syncing in realtime, that should be less expensive to reduce their amount to one and distinguish records by type.

But it should not be that costly, but still very convinient to set up multiple changes feed per each ItemStore (e.g. TodoStore, CommentStore, etc) with corresponding filter function passing only docs of the matching type into the store it belongs to. It can also be achieved by filtering on the basis of design_docs (I'm not sure if it saves anything, at least in the browser)

One change feed distributing docs to store would be probably the cheapest solution. But I suppose the filter function can't be changes after the change feed was established, so it must know about all the stores (i.e. doc types) beforehand

Comment: I agree with your point. But I have decided to continue with the current strategy and let me watch the performance for some months...